# How can I hide firefox from popping up during an integration spec?

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm using rspec, capybara and the selenium web-driver in Ubuntu to test my rails app.

I'd rather it if Firefox didn't keep popping up though, every time the spec is run. How can I hide this firefox window?

The window opens when the test is run and then disappears when the spec completes, so it's not something I can just minimize.

I use Chrome as my development and recreational browser though, so can I force Firefox to always minimize or something?

Or can I set some sort of preference in my spec_helper.rb?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into running firefox in xvfb.  This will further give you the option to run tests on a headless node later on.

If you go this route, I would also suggest incorporating a save screen shot method upon errors in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Firefox with -tray or -silent command line options. The former is supposed to open Firefox but keep it in the system tray and not open the windows. The latter is "Don't open default windows." I'm not quite sure what that means but give them a try.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Miscellaneous